# Screenshot from form

Tags: winforms, screenshot, minimize

I want to get screenshot of screen under my form, so I hide it first and show after capturing. But on my Windows 7 form is not completely minimize, so I get form on screenshot. How can I be sure that my form is competely minimize?

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
Bitmap screenshot = ScreenUtils.ScreenShot();
background = screenshot;
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

P.S. Hide() and Show() have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could set your forms opacity to 0, call refresh to make sure the painting is done, capture, reset opacity to 1 and call refresh again

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to build in a sleep before making a screenshot?

Comment: Yep, I know this solution but don't like it. I can't be sure in sleep value.